# bad_alloc::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int) when im trying to create a vector 470mb size

Tags: c++, stdvector

The most interesting in this case, that yesterday it's work okay.
i have no idea what causes the trouble

```
size = 480 000 000;
std::vector<char> result(size);
```

Comment: Close a few applications and try again ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The most interesting in this case, that yesterday it's work okay.

The contents of a `std::vector` are not stored in thin air; they occupy the memory in your computer. Obviously, the memory situation in your computer changes all the time. Either the total free space available became smaller since yesterday, or there is more fragmentation now, so that even if the total free space is well over 470MB, there is no free **contiguous** 470MB spot anywhere.

Perhaps a [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) can fix the problem elegantly enough in the short term:

> As opposed to `std::vector`, the elements of a deque are not stored
>   contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually
>   allocated fixed-size arrays, [...]

This comes with a few disadvantages, of course, as the same documentation explains.

Comment: thanks all for answer.
but i thought the vector data stored in RAM, isn't it?

Comment: @qqffx: Well, the "M" in "RAM" means "memory" :) So I'm afraid I don't understand your reply...

Comment: sorry for being ambiguous :)
is it really possible to have not a 480mb contiguous memory in 16gb ram?
with 30% loaded (by Task Manager) i mean

Answer (score 1):

Vector tries to allocate a **continuous** memory block of required size. Depending on system memory fragmentation there might be no 0.5Gb block available and your memory allocation fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocation a lot of contiguous memory so if you run out of memory you get bad_alloc.

Comment: What would `reserve` accomplish here?

Comment: agreed, useless